# Using up and down button to scroll the page banner upwards or downwards

Tags: php, javascript, html, scroll

I placed two buttons at the header 'up-arrow' and 'down arrow'. At the content area I placed multiple table which contain the banner image. Is it possible if I click on the upwards button the 1st table will scroll upwards and show the 2nd table and if it is the last table it will scroll up that 1st table. I want the rest of the table to be hidden as I still want the footer image to to be at the same position below the table.

here is my code for the table:

```
<div id="banner">
    <table width="750px" height="600px">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="sale_1.php"><img src="banner1.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="750px" height="600px">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="sale_2.php"><img src="banner2.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="750px" height="600px">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="sale_3.php"><img src="banner3.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

button:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/up_arrow.png"/></td>
<td><img src="images/down_arrow.png"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do it :

1) Put in a div the tables you want to make a scripted scrolling on.

2) Give an id to the div

3) Your buttons will adjust the value of yourDiv.scrollTop to move the content up or down.

Clear enough or you need an example ?

Comment: please give an example of how you apply the yourElement.scrollTop.

Comment: var yourDiv = document.getElementById("idOfYourDiv"); yourdiv.scrollTop += 5; //This will scroll the content 5 pixels down

Comment: So do I have to put that code into a javascript tag? And then create a div to contains all the 3 tables with an id 'banner'? so sorry that I have to ask this question..

Comment: Put the JS code in the click event listener of your *down* button. And yes, the div must contain your tables.

Comment: but my button is just an image. How do I apply the JS code to it?

Comment: <img src="someName.gif" onclick="scrollTablesDown()"> for example, with your function scrollTablesDown() defined in the HTML head section.